# Getting the size of a DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I am using a `DialogFragment` and would like to get the size of the `DialogFragment`.

Is it possible to get the size? And if it is, how would I accomplish that?

**EDIT:**
I need the width of the DialogFragment in pixels to be able to position an image properly.

Comment: Size? Phyiscal dimensions? For what purpose? This question needs more context.

Comment: @Phil I need the width in pixels to be able to position an image properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY to get view from fragment

```
View view = fragment.getView()
```

then get height and width from view

```
int width=view.getWidth();
int height=view.getHeight();
```

**::
OR you can try**

get Dialog from fragment

```
Dialog mDialog = dialogFragment.getDialog();
```

and get width and height (as dialog is shown)

```
int height=mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
int width=mDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getWidth();
```

Comment: Agreed. Find the outermost view component in the dialog and obtain the dimensions from there.

Answer (score 1):

you can get height through

```
getDialog().getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight() ;
```

you can get layoutParms and you can set height,

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.width = 200;
lp.height = 400;
lp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.LEFT;
getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```